# Parallel Coordinates Plot in TRAINS

Tags: python, deep-learning, trains, clearml

Is there a way to create a parallel coordinates plot in TRAINS (https://github.com/allegroai/trains) package to compare several hyper-parameters in respect to a specific metric?

Answer (score 1):

Declaimer: I'm a member of TRAINS team

I'm assuming something like https://plot.ly/python/sankey-diagram/#more-complex-sankey-diagram

Unfortunately it is not supported yet, you can always add a request in the GitHub issues.

That said, based on this [example](https://github.com/allegroai/trains/blob/master/docs/faq.md#can-i-create-a-graph-comparing-hyper-parameters-vs-model-accuracy-)
You could have 3 axis of hyper-parameter comparison (number_layers, lr_rate, accuracy):

```
Task.current_task().get_logger().report_scatter3d(
    "performance", "accuracy", iteration=0, 
    mode='markers', scatter=[(number_layers, lr_rate, accuracy)])
```

Or use the [custom column](https://github.com/allegroai/trains/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-sort-models-by-a-certain-metric-) option, and add one the hyper-parameter as an additional column.